# Can Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi Compile Code?

Tags: windows, compilation, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2

I know I can make a CPP or C# or any other "universal app" and deploy it to Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi, but can the Raspberry Pi running Windows compile code?
If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official Windows IoT FAQ](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Faqs.htm) says that Win32 console applications will run (but without a console display).

Therefore you can take any compiler that comes with source code and runs on Win32, compile it as a Win32 console app for the ARMv6 processor architecture, and deploy it on the Pi.  I guess you should also create a "universal app" as a UI to allow you to specify source filenames and command-line options.

Of course, the result will be in the binary format that compiler is programmed to produce.  I don't know of any C++ compiler that produces PE format files for ARMv6 and also has source code available.

On the other hand, Mono compiles C# into PE format pure-MSIL ("AnyCPU") executables, which should be fine.  And you can run those with either Microsoft's .NET or Mono, although not all desktop .NET functionality is supported.

- http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2014/08/31/mono-on-windows-iot-galileo/

Eventually, you might be able to get the MonoDevelop IDE working, [like people have done on Raspbian](https://www.maketecheasier.com/write-c-sharp-programs-raspberry-pi/)